# What database is supported by iOS for a web application?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, html

Does it support indexed DB? I want to run the application on iPhone.

Comment: Sorry but this is just too broad of a question. A google search would produce much better results. Next time, please post questions to which you have a code snippet to show and ask for help

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

iOS comes with sqlite3 - avert small efficient database you can use.